# How can we convert the data received into JSON format in Python

Tags: python, url

I am getting a data using GET method in Python and again i am posting the data i got to another URL using POST method using python Script. But while posting I am getting ERROR 400 BAD REQUEST - which I think because of the data format i am sending to the URL.

The Post URL I am using will accept J SON format.The data I got is in TYPE DICT. 
Can you give me some example for how to convert the data and send to URL?

Comment: `json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you are looking for:

```
import json

artistDict = {
  'name'     : 'Davy Jones',
  'band'     : 'Monkeys',
  'Genre'    : 'Rock',
  'firstYear': 1966
}
artist_json = json.dumps(artistDict)
print(artist_json)
```

will produce

```
{"name": "Davy Jones", "band": "Monkeys", "Genre": "Rock", "firstYear": 1966}
```

You would then be able to send `artist_json` to your receiving application

Answer (score 1):

try something like this and let me know,

```
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(dict_data))
```